# sapply to POSIXct vector returns wrong values?

Tags: r, as.date

The codes and results shown below:

```
(p <- as.POSIXct(c("2017-09-21 UTC", "2017-09-22 UTC")))
[1] "2017-09-21 PDT" "2017-09-22 PDT"

as.Date(p)
[1] "2017-09-21" "2017-09-22"

(d <- sapply(p, as.Date))
[1] 17430 17431
```

Why the sapply returns a numeric vector?

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)

Comment: This is due to the `simplify=TRUE` defualt argument, that simplifies it to an array / matrix which can't hold date class `matrix(as.Date(p))`

Comment: *If simplification occurs* (and it does here), *the output type is determined from the highest type of the return values in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression, after coercion of pairlists to lists.* - `help(sapply)`

Comment: @user20650 That looks worth posting as an answer.